# Proxy config via DHCP

Tags: windows-7, proxy

I would like to know which proxy server I'm using. So far I only know it's being distributed via DHCP. IS there any chance to get this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Web Proxy Autodiscovery Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Autodiscovery_Protocol) defines multiple channels for a client to retrieve a [proxy configuration script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config):

- DHCP Option 252 (contains URL)
- DNS Trial and error, where `local.domain.example.com` is the local domain:

  1. `http://wpad.local.domain.example.com/wpad.dat`
  2. `http://wpad.domain.example.com/wpad.dat`
  3. `http://wpad.example.com/wpad.dat`
  4. ...
- NetBIOS trial and error, similar to DNS

Unfortunately, I do not know of a simple (Windows) solution to see what the DHCP server is dishing out. You could try to capture it with [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) though, if you are allowed administrative access to your computer.

Comment: I am already past the "try and error" suggestion of yours. I try wireshark.

Comment: I captured now the packets during my connection to the network. what now? what do i need to look for? There is like ton of information and all gibberish too

Comment: There's two things you can do: Filter for DHCP or filter for HTTP. The former tells you about DHCP traffic, which, according to the Wikipedia article, should be handled by the browser. The latter shows the proxy your browser is connecting to, if any.

Comment: I couldn't figure anything out with you filtering suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You can try this site [Lagado](http://www.lagado.com/proxy-test).  I have tried it on my network and it reports the correct proxy being used.

Comment: This is also an option, but only works if the proxy advertises its presence.